# Python: maketrans/translate equivalent to decode 3-character code into 1 character

Tags: python, decoding

I need to translate string that looks like this: `TAGGGC` into `fa` (`TAG->f`, `GGC->a`, where encrypted values can not only be letters but also some special characters). I am aware of `string.maketrans()` and `translate()` but these work only for 1-1 decoding.

Is there any other native Python module/function I could use in this case or should I just write my own function?

Comment: What about `str.replace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's more complicated than your example, you can define a little func based on `re.sub` that takes a dict, as input.

```
In [98]: def repl(d, s):
     ...:     p = re.compile('|'.join(d))
     ...:     return p.sub(lambda m:d[m.group()], s)

In [99]: d = {'TAG':'f',
              'GGC':'a'}

In [100]: repl(d,'TAGGGC')
Out[100]: 'fa'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
mystring.replace("TAG","f").replace("GGC","a")
```

If there are additional constrains, then you may need to fall back on `re.sub`